# MongoDB Node.js group by calculated key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new to Mongo Node.js driver. My problem is, I have set up a timestamp (in miliseconds) field in Mongo, and now I try to group it by seconds. Timestamp is a number (Int64), I want to have it grouped and counted with division by 1000.

My MongoDB Shell query works fine:

```
db.default.group(
{
    keyf: function(doc) {
    var secs = (doc.timestamp/1000).toFixed();
    return {'data':secs};
    },
    cond: {source:1},
    initial: {count:0},
    reduce: function(obj, prev) {prev.count++;}
})
```

My problem is I can't get to work my Node.js query:

```
var keyf = function(doc) {
        var secs = (doc.timestamp/1000).toFixed();
        return {'data': secs};
};
collection.group(keyf, {}, {"count":0},
      "function(obj, prev){prev.count++;}", false, function(err,results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

It looks as if group never noticed keyf function. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the aggregation framework for this? It's faster than server-side javascript methods. The hitch is I think it'll be hard to implement the truncation-by-division-by-1000 logic in the aggregation framework. Could you explain where that requirement is coming from? You  have a time in milliseconds and you want to group documents by the second?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I want to group by second while I only have miliseconds. The requirement is that I want to measure performance and I HAVE to count it in milis for precision in different calculations. On the other hand I want to have seconds to make it possible to put it into the diagram (plot) with numbers. Aggregating it within server, would be doing what DB is for. The other solution (which I can't find across the web) is to send the query to DB and return to the server the results. In node.js.

Comment: It would work in the aggregation framework if your timestamps were date type instead of numbers. I would always advise using a date type for time values. Could you switch?

Comment: I am not sure. I have to do timestamps in Java app which puts it all into mongo. I cannot make a timestamp directly on DB. I don't know whether it is possible to perform such a mongo timestamp within running Java program. Fair enough, the problem would be easy then, I admit that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.group` method on `collection`, Alternatively you have to use Model

```
Model.find({}, function(err, docs) { 
    if(err) console.error(err);
    if(!docs) console.log("No docs found!");

    function updater(docs){
        // Get first item of documents 
        doc = docs.unshift();

        // Change
        doc.timestamp = (doc.timestamp/1000).toFixed();

        // Update
        doc.save(function(err){
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                updater(docs); 
        });
    }
    // Update documents in async
    updater(docs);
});
```

Comment: After some research I discovered the Model thing, I can see it is from Mongoose package, while I am using mongodb package. Nevertheless, I don't want to have it updated, I need it first aggregated by timestamp divided by 1000 and then counted.